# XP clients having trouble accessing Server 2008 shares

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp

I have problem with my Windows Server 2008 file sharing.

Some time the users on XP system disconnect from the file server, but the users with Windows 7 never have a problem.

My physical network is 100Mb fully switched with 3Com switches. The ping from both side is good (<1ms), but the file server still disconnects the XP users.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what the problem **actually is**? As John said, disconnected sessions are not uncommon and not always bad. Are your users getting error messages? Unable to copy files? Or is it just the connections dissapear after an idle period?

Comment: when you say the XP system disconnects from the file server do you mean a mapped drive is disconnected? or could it be when you try to access files a message is recieved saying file/path cannot be found?

Comment: hello 
actually the users don't get any message,but they are disconnected from server ,whereas the ping is positive, but the win7 users haven't any problem.that is th all

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP doesn't maintain a constant open connection to network shares. After some time (I can't remember how long) with no activity it flags the connection as disconnected, which is signified by the red cross on the share when viewed in Windows Explorer. Despite the appearance, it's only a matter of initiating any sort of traffic, such as browsing the share, to flag it as established again.

Comment: Hey John. I missed your 10k day! Belated congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some WinXP-specific timeout ?

- https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6061505.html
- http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/86713-45-losing-network-shares-time-login